# How can I get the pitch, yaw, and roll of an Android device from 0 - 360 degrees?

Tags: android, kotlin, accelerometer, android-sensors, gyroscope

So this is apparently quite a simple question but I haven't been able to find a 100% working solution despite my research and googling over the last few months.  Basically, I just want to obtain the pitch, yaw and roll from an Android device represented from 0 to 360 degrees.

Most functionality I have seen that accomplishes this seems to boil down to code that looks like the following:

```
  private fun updateOrientation(rotationVector: FloatArray) {
        val rotationMatrix = FloatArray(9)
        SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(rotationMatrix, rotationVector)

        val (worldAxisForDeviceAxisX, worldAxisForDeviceAxisY) = when (mWindowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation) {
            Surface.ROTATION_0 -> Pair(SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z)
            Surface.ROTATION_90 -> Pair(SensorManager.AXIS_Z, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X)
            Surface.ROTATION_180 -> Pair(SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z)
            Surface.ROTATION_270 -> Pair(SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_Z, SensorManager.AXIS_X)
            else -> Pair(SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z)
        }

        val adjustedRotationMatrix = FloatArray(9)
        SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(rotationMatrix, worldAxisForDeviceAxisX,
                worldAxisForDeviceAxisY, adjustedRotationMatrix)

        // Transform rotation matrix into azimuth/pitch/roll
        val orientation = FloatArray(3)
        SensorManager.getOrientation(adjustedRotationMatrix, orientation)

        // Convert radians to degrees
        val pitch = orientation[1] * -57
        val roll = orientation[2] * -57
        println("pitch is $pitch")
        println("roll is $roll")



        mListener?.onOrientationChanged(pitch, roll)
    }
```

However, when I run this on my physical device, and I *roll* the device from side to side (that is, put the device on approximately 45 degree angle either way), when I roll to the left I get readings like 95 degrees, and when I roll to the right I get readings like -95.  If I roll the phone and then leave it, the roll angle (while the phone is flat on the desk) goes between 140 and 160 before finally stabilising at ~144-145 degrees.

Pitch behaves in a more reasonable manner (starts at -90, goes to -74 if I tilt the phone up and down).

I would *expect* that the roll of the device would start at 0 or 180, as the phone is flat on the desk.  If I tilted the device 45 degrees to the left, I would get a reading of 135.  If I tilted it 45 degrees to the right, I would get readings like 225.

I'm starting to think that I could critically misunderstand the accelerometer/gyroscope functionality in android and physical devices and what I want to accomplish is physically impossible.  I am trying to get this data so I can set up a "safe range" of angles for my app (if the phone is at less than a certain angle, or more than a certain angle for a certain amount of time, it sounds an alert).

How can I get the pitch, yaw, and roll of the device from 0 - 360 degrees on an Android device?

Comment: Take a look at my library https://github.com/hoananguyen/dsensor-lib. You have to startDSensor with TYPE_ROLL or TYPE_PITCH and or either getCompass or get3DCompass and then convert to degree from radian. Look at samples for example.

Comment: Cool.  I see you're the creator of this library, is it okay with you if I write a flutter plugin for it?  It seems to give the information that I'm after which is great :D.  Also, I hear that using "euler angles" can result in things like gimbal lock.  If I convert the returned data to degrees or angles, do I run that risk?  I'm not great at vector maths so if my questions are weird or don't make sense its definitely a me thing :)

Comment: There is no gimbal lock in my library. If you register for compass, it will return an error which says that the device is not flat and therefore no compass direction. If you register for 3D compass, then in this case it will give you camera direction. Of course you can folk and do whatever you want